# Trying to save an item from a dropdown display list in a string, in my C# web app

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I've been trying to teach myself C# and am currently trying to make a "Truck Quality Test" data storage / display app. I'm using standard VS MVC web app with Razor and Entity for SQL.

I'm trying to save my data from user input into a SQL database, and the truck name is going to be selected from a dropdown menu. However, I'm getting the error

InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 'TruckName' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GetSelectListItems(ViewContext viewContext, string expression)

I'm using the "Select List Item" to store my truck names, and it's really been trick to deal with. Can anyone help?

Dropdown list in controller + create

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        PopulateTrucksDropDownList();
        return View();
    }



    // POST: TruckTests/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("TruckName,ComponentTested,TestType,TestDate,Score")] TruckTest truckTest)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(truckTest);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(truckTest);
    }
```

Dropdown form

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TruckName,
                 ViewBag.TrucksList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
                 "Select a truck",
                 new { @class = "form-control" }
                 )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TruckName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Model class-

```
    public class TruckTest
{
    // Use the name of the truck as the primary key
    [Key] public string TruckName { get; set; }
    public string ComponentTested { get; set; }
    public string TestType { get; set; }
    public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    // This will be used to populate the dropdown in the view
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Truck { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please don't link to external code. Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: A good reason why we don't link like this is that your third link is broken.

Comment: Apologies @Enigmativity, this is my first SO question.  Updated.

Comment: I think this answer might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34366306/22955157